# YA SF story : Antéor is the guide to the world of the electron

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, space

Well, this one is a long shot.

I read this YA short fiction (novelette size, I think) when I was ...YA, in the mid-sixties. It was in French and certainly the original. Whether it was ever translated into english is not guaranteed.

A human-looking alien befriends a group of people (IIRC, adults and children). He says he comes from the stars and asks to be called "Antéor" because like the giant Antée (Antaeus in English) he has touched Earth, when coming from the "or" (gold) of the stars. Clearly the pun only works in French !

He offers the group a chance to visit the people who live on an electron. Even at that time the "solar system model" of the atom was totally obsolete, but, well, it was **YA** SF ! To shrink them he uses a drug called "négacolchicine" (or maybe "negacolchicine" ?)

So everyone is shrunk to sub-sub-atomic size, and meet people who live on an electron.

Nice people, nice meeting, nice talking, nice good-byes, I don't remember anything special about the remainder of the story.

Searching "négacolchicine", "Antéor" with or without acute accent did not bring anything.

Anthéor (with H) is a nice place in Southern France where I go occasionally and which reminds me of the story each time, but it has nothing to do with it. Since Antéor did come from interstellar space I mention "space" as a tag, because I could not find a tag for "shrunk to sub-atomic scale"

Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: I think the fact that searching for "négacolchicine" doesn't match _anything_ (except, now, this question) means one of two things.  First, that the story has never been scanned or otherwise put on line or, two, that you've misremembered.  I have no idea which is more likely, but you can't do much about the first, so you might consider if there might be a slightly different name.  Maybe still colchicine, but with a different prefix?

Comment: @DavidW Well, your search engine is better than mine, because I still cannot find négacolchicine. I tried 8 variants néga-colchicine and négo-colchicine, each with and without acute accent and/or hyphen. Got nothing. I knew it was based on "neg" because I remember (how little details come back, when I forgot most of the story) that Antéor formed this word on "négentropie". Now it is quite possible it was never scanned. YA, you know, and not really that good even for YA.  If it were not for the place called Anthéor, I would probably have completely forgotten about it.

Comment: Now if it was translated into english, and only the translation was scanned, maybe anti-colchicin  (with or w/o hyphen) ? But my research engine did not give anything. Since yours is better, could you try that ?

Comment: Nothing useful from "anti-colchicine," though it is a thing; there are numerous papers and mentions in biology texts about anti-colchicine antibodies in sheep, for instance.  I wonder why the author picked colchicine?  It's a naturally occurring compound, mildly toxic in moderate amounts but in tiny amounts used as a gout medication.  It seems weird to use it as the basis of a shrinking potion.

Comment: @DavidW Not so weird. In fact I remember the argument. Among the various toxic effect of colchicin, it prevents cells in embryo to differenciate. At least that was what the author wrote. So the embryo increases in size wthout cell differenciation. If one stops the colchicin poisoning the embryo starts to evolve more or less normally but ends up much **bigger** than it should. I think giant baby rabbits were described. So if instead of colchicin you have negacolchicin you get dwarves.

Comment: @DavidW Of course, that might work during a pregnancy (of rabbit, of lab animal!) you'd get early tissue differenciation leading to small rabbits. Changing an already born human to a size fitting on a small part of an electron (supposedly spherical !)  is totally absurd, but the "colchicin increases size" "negacolchicin reduces size", well, that was Antéor's logic.... I beg to differ! LOL

Comment: Ray Cummings wrote [The Girl from Infinite Smallness](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/61698/pg61698-images.html), which has some similarities, including characters with vaguely French sounding names, such as Artone.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks, but it's not it, from waht  Isaw on the link you provided. No "terrified princess", no "evil  Taroh". Everyone is nice, information is exchanged between macroscopic and microscopic, is the best possible terms.

Comment: @Alfred Thought it might be a long shot. I think all the sub-atomic ones I know involve some sort of evil character aiming a world domination or similar.

Comment: @bob1 Well, not that one. But probably you never heard of it. YA, and not such a great one at that. If it weren't for the "plateau d'Anthéor", in the "Massif de l'Esterel" that reminds me of it, I probably would have forgot all about it, and it would have fallen into oblivion...

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of French Science Fiction writers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:French_science_fiction_writers) if that helps.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks but no. I don't remember the name of the author and  such a long list does not help.